# Disabling @login_required while unit-testing flask with flask-login

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, webtest, flask-login

I am unit testing my flask app which uses the flask-login extension.

I am setting up all my tests like this using webtest:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.client = webtest.TestApp(app)
```

But when I try to visit urls through self.client.get() which are decorated with @login_required, I get a 401 error with a message that I am not authorized to access the url.

According to the documentation https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#protecting-views
and this [discussion](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/pull/104),
setting the config value of 'TESTING' to True should disable the login requirements, but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This because `Flask-Login` caching `TESTING` or `LOGIN_DISABLED` on `init_app` (https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login.py#L164).

So if you create application and then set something in config then you config changes will ignored.

Better way use application factory with separated configs for production and tests, it also decrease probability get errors with not cleaned application state in tests.

The easiest way reinit `login_manager`:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.login_manager.init_app(app)
        self.client = webtest.TestApp(app)
```

Comment: Seems to work with `LOGIN_DISABLED` but not with `TESTING`. https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/216

Answer (score 6):

from [flask login documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#protecting-views)  it's said that :

> It can be convenient to globally turn off authentication when unit
>   testing. To enable this, if the application configuration variable
>   LOGIN_DISABLED is set to True, this decorator will be ignored.

if you are using application factory design pattern add this to  your testing config :

```
LOGIN_DISABLED = True
```

or you can add it while creating the app like this :

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True
        self.client = webtest.TestApp(app)
```

Hope this will help the others who will have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but:

in my old flaskr project file, I had the configurations in my "flaskr.py" file, and they looked like this:

```
# configuration
DATABASE = 'flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'
```

So maybe you would have

```
TESTING = True
```

?

Comment: As you can see from my code above, I am setting the TESTING configuration variable for the app before each test. During debugging, I've checked the config and indeed TESTING is set to True.