# Flask unittesting API requests

Tags: flask

I am trying to write unit test cases for flas api server.
Can someeone please suggest ow to get rid of `auth.login_required`.

Tried mocking auth, but of no use.

with `test_client` its not hitting code block too.

**api.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    print "In index"
    response.status_code = 200
    return response
```

Tried following http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/

```
from src.api import app
from unittest import TestCase

class TestIntegrations(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
    def test_thing(self):
        response = self.app.get('/')
```

Can someone please help ??

Comment: Your client should send Basic auth credentials with every request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47096509/4683950 see my answer at that link and let me know if it help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do so - first is to disable authorization in tests:

```
// in your test module 
from api import app, auth
import unittest

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(user, password):
    """Overwrite password check to always pass.

    This works even if we send no auth data."""
    return True
```

Another approach is to actually send the auth headers from tests (this way you can also test your authorization system):

```
from api import app
from base64 import b64encode
import unittest


class ApiClient:
    """Performs API requests."""

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        """Sends GET request and returns the response."""
        return self.client.get(url, headers=self.request_headers(), **kwargs)

    def request_headers(self):
        """Returns API request headers."""
        auth = '{0}:{1}'.format('user', 'secret')
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic {encoded_login}'.format(
                encoded_login=b64encode(auth.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
            )
        }


class TestIntegrations(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = ApiClient(app)

    def test_thing(self):
        response = self.app.get('/')
        print(response.data)
```

The `ApiClient` helper can also define `post`, `delete` methods which will be similar to `get`.

The full source code with examples is [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/python-flask-unittest).