# Why am I unable to pass a unit test with function that contains a @login_required in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am writing a unit test for a function in my python flask and the function contains a @login_required. I am only trying to check whether the function is being called properly and gives out the same status code of 200 or not.
Here is my function which resides in app.py

```
@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def settings():
    global application_inst
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Setting changed")

    return render_template('settings.html', user=session['user'], application=application_inst)
```

and this is how I have written my test case in a testcase file test_app.py which is present in my tests folder.

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(db)
        self.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

        with self.app.app_context():
            # create all tables
            db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_settings_passed(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            response = self.client.get('/settings', follow_redirects=True)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The error that is being displayed is an AssertionError which says that 200!=404.
please see the stacktrace

```
st_app_new.py::MyTestCase::test_settings FAILED                        [100%]ENV :default
############ INIT ############
############ INIT ############
############ INIT ############

 
200 != 404

Expected :404
Actual   :200
<Click to see difference>

self = <test_app_new.MyTestCase testMethod=test_settings>, first = 404
second = 200, msg = None

    def _patched_equals(self, first, second, msg=None):
        try:
>           old(self, first, second, msg)

/snap/pycharm-community/214/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/teamcity/diff_tools.py:32: 


Assertion failed
```

I have tried to test the function by testing the testing the request from the logged in user.
This is how I did it.

```
    def test_settings(self):
        with self.app.test_client() as c:
            with c.session_transaction() as sess:
                sess['user_id'] = 'leadgenuser'
                sess['fresh'] = True
            response = c.get('/settings')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

and even this failed and returned the same error. What I wanted from this test case was that upon asserting the response equal to 200 the testcase should pass,but at present it is failing. I have even tried to comment out the @login_required from the function but that gave the same error. Please help me understand where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling @login\_required while unit-testing flask with flask-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765210/disabling-login-required-while-unit-testing-flask-with-flask-login)

Comment: @simkus that gives a similar error except earlier it was giving an Assertion Error now it gives an App error,but the status code 200!=404 remains the same.

Comment: Then either this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119814/8843270 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563430/8843270 might help. Other then that,

Comment: Also this one gives help on how to test flask-login, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506326/testing-flask-login-and-authentication

Comment: @simkus unfortunately none of them worked :(